# Rewrite Rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I asked this question in Stackoverflow but one of the respondents told me to ask it in here instead. I wonder if this is something that can be done in htaccess?

I have this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/folder/New.jsp?par=new1
```

...which I want to redirect to:

```
 https://www.example.com/folder/New.jsp
```

how should I do that?

Basically I have `par=new1|new2|new3|new4` that would like to be redirected to `https://www.example.com/folder/New.jsp`.

Any help from you will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the parameters taken off, it's pretty straight forward

```
RedirectMatch https://www.website.com/folder/New.jsp(\?par=.[a-z])  https://www.website.com/folder/New.jsp
```

No mod_rewrite needed.

Comment: Thanks, sysadmin. I'm pretty new with this mod_rewrite so please forgive me with my naive question. I tried to place this code in .htacess along with other redirects but it gave our site a 404. So I also tried placing it under the RewriteEngine  on
RewriteOptions inherit but nothing happens. Where should this be placed?

Comment: This directive won't do anything. The mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive matches against the URL-path only - which notably excludes the protocol, hostname and query string. To match the query string you need to use mod_rewrite as stated in [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/961842/49157).

Answer (score 0):

In order to match specific URL parameters, you need to use mod_rewrite with a *condition* that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. The mod_alias `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives match against the URL-path only and can not be used to check the query string.

Try the following near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^par=(new1|new2|new3|new4) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/New\.jsp$ /$0 [NC,QSD,R,L]
```

The `QSD` flag (requires Apache 2.4) on the `RewriteRule` directive *discards* the original query string from the redirected URL. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then use a `?` at the end of the *substitution* string instead. For example: `RewriteRule ^folder/New\.jsp$ /$0? [NC,R,L]`.

`$0` is a backreference to the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `folder/New.jsp`.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If a 301 (permanent) redirect is required then change the `R` flag to read `R=301`.